# Pareamento temporal de dados do mercado financeiro baixados pelo pacote Batchgetsymbols no R

Tags: r

Através do código a seguir, importo os dados da bolsa de valor o Índice Ibovespa, da Petrobrás e do Índice Americano S&P 500. Entretanto, as datas das observações não são exatamente correspondentes

```
# Carregar pacote de importação de dados da bolsa
library(BatchGetSymbols)

# Inputs
# data inicial
first.date <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
#data final
last.date <- Sys.Date()
#frequencia das observações
freq.data <- 'daily'
# Ativos a serem baixados
tickers <- c("^BVSP","PETR4.SA","^GSPC")

#função que baixa ativos
ativos <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') )
```

Alguém saberia me informar um jeito de parear temporalmente os dados, ou seja, ter apenas observações de datas com valores para os três ativos, eliminando dos dados aquelas datas em que há observação para apenas um ou dois ativos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), uma opção é agrupar por data e manter apenas aquelas observações cujo grupo tenha mais de dois membros

```
library(tidyverse)

ativos[[2]] %>% 
  group_by(ref.date) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2)
# A tibble: 1,416 x 10
# Groups:   ref.date [472]
# ...
```

Comment: não consegui implementar

Comment: Qual foi o problema que apareceu?

Comment: desculpe a demora, consegui resolver o problema com sua sugestão, muito obrigado